# Interactive mouse click on the image area in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I want to click/doubleclick on the image and start `impoly`.
Something like :

```
if(user perform 'doubleclick' on the image in image area (matlab gui))
    % polygon start to create
    bw = impoly...
end
```

I would like to create more polygons on the image (one after the other).

Comment: Could you please add more information and post the code you have for the issue at hand? As it is your question is hard to understand.

Comment: Using `impoly` is a good idea. Post the solution you have right now and explain the issues you have with it. Learn how to use the `ButtonDownFcn` [axes property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can typically detect any mouse interaction with the image using the [`ButtonDownFcn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image-properties.html#property_ButtonDownFcn) of the image object. You can then (within that callback) check the [`SelectionType`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_SelectionType) property of the parent figure to determine what type of click it was

```
h = imshow(rand(100));

% Setup callback function for mouse events on the image
set(h, 'ButtonDownFcn', @my_callback)

function my_callback(src, evnt)

    % Get the selection type
    type = get(gcbf, 'SelectionType');

    % If it was a double click....
    if strcmpi(type, 'open')
        bw = impoly(...);
    end
end
```